# batch file with loop and without console

Tags: loops, batch-file, console

I have batch file that run on windows:

```
SET /A XCOUNT=29
:start
SET /A XCOUNT+=1
java -Xms2048m -Xmx3072m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC  -jar newsrvrSodfa.jar >.\loging\log%XCOUNT%.txt
goto start
```

as seen, I have a loop, my question, How to run this file without showing consol, and in the same time without loosing the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start "" /b java -Xms2048m -Xmx3072m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC  -jar newsrvrSodfa.jar >.\loging\log%XCOUNT%.txt
```

?

[start /b](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) option is for not creating a new window

Comment: thanx :  
and the loop will note lose?

Comment: Consider `/WAIT` option as well: `start "" /b /WAIT java ...`